# How to rollback a single file backed up with rsync?

Tags: rsync, incremental-backup

I just set up a linux NAS as an rsync server to backup our file server. I'm saving several versions of each file and know how to restore a snapshot of our server, but what we really need is to rollback a single file. We work with large CAD files which occasionally become corrupt. Using rysnc, how do I list all of the versions of a single file and then specify one to be restored? I'd be OK with doing this either on the server using SSH or with a Windows client app.

Comment: Please provide the full rsync command line you use when you back up. Also, I suggest rdiff-backup as an alternative. It is similar, but has better incremental support.

Comment: Our file system is a Synology NAS and the rsync backup is specified by its client app "Backup and Restore". I took a closer look at it and see that it only backs up multiple copies of the system configuration, not of the data files. I.e., it has minimal control over the backup. So, I can't do it through the client app and need to specify it on the server side. Thanks for the recommendation on rdiff-backup. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its difficult to answer your question as put as there is not enough information about "the NAS".

From a general point of view, you should simply be able to find the appropriate file in the rsync and copy it across.   The whole idea of rsync is that the file tree for each version is complete, so you can copy a single file or directory or what have you, with the only concern being the date of the restore.  (rsync does this trick by using symlinks for unchanged files, thus if a file is unchanged between versions there is 1 file, but it appears as multiple files - one in each backup.

Thus, if you can browse the appropriate snapshot you should be able to just download it if your NAS allows that, otherwise you could use scp or(SSH's copy program) or sftp (ssh version of FTP - which should allow you to browse the filesystem) to copy the file off the NAS.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on symlinks. It wasn't clear to me how iterative backups are organized, so your comment clarified thinks. As described in my comment above, I'm not getting multiple data backups as I thought after all and need to look at another setup.

Comment: Actually, its my mistake as well, sorry.  RSYNC only provides a single copy - RSNAPSHOT typically uses rsync and symlinks to create multiple versions of the directories using symlinks [ and it uses rsync to do the file transfers ]